# JSON data changing after Promise is resolved in React SharePoint Framework web part

Tags: json, reactjs, odata, azure-active-directory, spfx

I'm making a call to an ODATA API, and the results of the JSON are changing after the promise is resolved.

Code block:

```
return client
.get(apiQueryString, AadHttpClient.configurations.v1)
.then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    else {
        console.warn(response);
        return;
    }
})
.then((json: { value: INewBusinessProps[] }) =>{
    return json.value;
})
```

If I throw in a `console.log(response.json());` after the `if (response.ok)` line, I get the data back correctly:

```
{first_name: "Fake", last_name: "User", user_type: "billing"}
{first_name: "Fake", last_name: "User", user_type: "originating"}
{first_name: "Fake", last_name: "User", user_type: "responsible"}
```

However, when I add `console.log(json.value)` after the line `.then((json: { value: INewBusinessProps[] }) =>{`, I get:

```
{first_name: "Fake", last_name: "User", user_type: "originating"}
{first_name: "Fake", last_name: "User", user_type: "originating"}
{first_name: "Fake", last_name: "User", user_type: "originating"}
```

(note the user_type)

Running from a browser or fiddler gives me the correct results; it's only after the `then` that the data gets messed up.

I also thought it might be the type `INewBusinessProps[]` that was the problem, so I changed it to `any[]` and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It was a syntax error. Later in the code, I was filtering by user_type and had

```
return person
.filter(p => p.user_type = userType)
```

which was setting the user_type instead of comparing it. Changed it to:

```
return person
.filter(p => p.user_type == userType)
```

and it works.